# Esse caminho é valido para todos os dispositivos?

Tags: java, android, armazenamento

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo . Ele possui a função de salvar imagem em uma pasta própria do app.E estou utilizando o seguinte código :

```
 File file = new File("storage/emulated/0/PastaTeste/");//PastaTeste é a pasta do app
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdir();
        }
        File image = new File(file, name + ".png");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
    }
```

> **O meu medo é de "storage/emulated/0 não ser válido em todos os dispositivos .Tem algum método que obtenha o armazenamento externo primário?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve pegar o diretório que deseja através de métodos do Android, pois é comum isso mudar de versão para versão por motivos de segurança e permissão. Hoje, por exemplo, do Android Q (API 29) em diante um app **não** consegue acessar diretamente pastas ou arquivos externos à ele.

O método que era utilizado (e agora está *deprecated*) é o [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)). Segue tradução livre do aviso oficial:

> **Este método foi descontinuado na API 29.**
>
> Para melhorar a privacidade do usuário, o acesso direto a dispositivos de armazenamento compartilhado / externo foi descontinuado. Quando um aplicativo tem como alvo a versão **`Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`**, o caminho retornado desse método não fica mais diretamente acessível. Os aplicativos podem continuar acessando o conteúdo armazenado no armazenamento compartilhado / externo, migrando para alternativas como [Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) ou [Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).

---

## Arquivos e diretórios internos do app

Caso você queira acessar um arquivo ou diretório que é do **seu app**, então siga a recomendação da documentação e use `getExternalFilesDir(String tipo)`. A partir da versão **`Build.VERSION_CODE.KITKAT`** (API 19), não é necessário permissões para leitura ou escrita no diretório do seu app. Note que, quando o seu aplicativo for desinstalado ou o usuário limpar os dados dele, o conteúdo dessa pasta será removido.

> Retorna caminhos absolutos para diretórios específicos do aplicativo
>   em todos os dispositivos de armazenamento compartilhados / externos,
>   nos quais o aplicativo pode colocar arquivos persistentes que possui.
>   Esses arquivos são internos ao aplicativo e normalmente não são
>   visíveis ao usuário como mídia.

Se você fornecer um `tipo` não nulo, o arquivo retornado será um caminho para um subdiretório do tipo especificado. Exemplo: `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`.

Então, ao utilizar o `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, o seu retorno será algo como `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.seupacote/`.

E no seu código, seria aplicado assim:

```java
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "PastaTeste");
```

---

## O usuário escolhe o arquivo ou diretório

Caso você precise acessar um arquivo ou diretório externo, você pode usar um [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) e então o usuário poderá navegar com um **gerenciador de arquivos** e escolher algum. Note que há chance do usuário não ter um gerenciador de arquivos no celular. Já trabalhei com esse modo e em alguns celulares eu precisei instalar o app Google Drive para o usuário escolher um arquivo na nuvem.

Recomendo fortemente a leitura de [Access documents and other files from shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files), pois lá existem diferentes exemplos e casos de uso.

> Em dispositivos que executam o **Android 4.4 (API 19)** e superior,
>   seu aplicativo pode interagir com um [provedor de documentos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider),
>   incluindo volumes de armazenamento externo e armazenamento baseado em
>   nuvem, usando o *Storage Access Framework*.

Para o usuário realizar a escolha do arquivo/diretório, você usará um **`Intent`**. Nesse exemplo, o arquivo selecionado terá seu conteúdo lido pelo app:

```java
private final int PICK_FILE = 1;

// Chame esse método no clique de um botão, por exemplo
private void onPickFileClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent()
            .setType("text/*") // Qualquer arquivo do tipo texto
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // Leitura do conteúdo
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Escolha um arquivo"), PICK_FILE);
}
```

E quando o usuário escolher o arquivo, **`onActivityResult`** será chamado:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // O "resultData" contém uma URI para o arquivo
        // ou diretório que o usuário selecionou, podendo ser "null"
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso , no android Q , não há um jeito de obter o armazenamento externo livre? pois esse método acessa a pasta data em android , e eu queria obter diretamente o armazenamento externo, como fazia o outro metódo que está deprecated .

Comment: Você pode utilizar um `Intent` e o usuário escolhe a pasta/arquivo. O próprio app fazer isso não é possível por motivo de privacidade, como dito no _warning_ do método

Comment: Ok, entendi . muito obrigado.

Comment: Adicionei à resposta referências à documentação para acessar arquivos/diretórios externos ao app. Também coloquei o exemplo com o Intent que eu utilizei em um aplicativo meu que estava em `Kotlin` (então talvez tenha pequenos erros na tradução que fiz pra `Java`)

Comment: Outra duvida. Será que eu consigo criar um pasta para o app na pasta pictures no android Q?aquela padrão que já vem no android. será que dá para criar uma pasta ali dentro com o android novo?

Comment: Acredito que com [**`MediaStore`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) você consiga, dá uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370669/file-operations-in-android-q-beta) do SOen, mas não cheguei a mexer com MediaStore para dizer.